# Does MS Office JavaScript API for Word include all the functionality of VSTO/VBA?

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-interop, office-addins

I have a very big and complex project in VBA that parses and changes the content of word documents in a variety of ways. I need to decide whether to rewrite it in .NET VSTO or using the newer Javascript API for web/desktop.

As of 2022, is this API identical to the VBA/VSTO versions in its abilities, regarding Word and the common office API? I can't seem to get a clear response from Microsoft on this.

My concern is that after a lot of work I would stumble on properties that they have simply not implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the Office JavaScript Library (Office.js) doesn't support all the things in VBA/VSTO. If all of the end-users are on Windows computers, you could re-implement in VSTO. If you'd like cross platform support (Windows, Mac, online), you have to hope that what you need is supported in the Office.js. But the only way to find out is to go through your existing code and, for every functionality used, see if there are methods in Office.js that will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It does not, unfortunately. Currently, there's no full-functionality replacement for VBA/VSTO. Unless your aim is to have your project working on the web (Online Office365/phones/tablets), I don't think it is worth it.